# How to change the active color of a link if a:active isn't working?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get just the class="H" inside each link to change color when that link is selected. I have tried to use `a:active{ color:#17CCB2; }` and then 
`.H a:active { color:#17CCB2; }` in the CSS and neither seems to change the color when I click the links. Here is my HTML snippet:

```
<div class="solution">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="FirstLink" href="javascript:" onclick="changeImg('images/auto-simp.gif');"><p class="solution-body"><span class="H">Auto Simplify</span><br>Automatically applies the Simplify Graphics for users that don't have the design tools, skills, or time to apply the SUI technique to their content.</p></a></li>
        <li><a id="AC" href="javascript:" onclick="changeImg('images/auto-colors@2x.png')"><p class="solution-body"><span class="H">Auto Color Palette</span><br>Technical communicators and trainers often deal with content that regularly updates or needs to be translated for multiple languages.</p></a></li>
        <li><a id="SG" href="javascript:" onclick="changeImg('images/simplifylaptop@2x.png')"><p class="solution-body"><span class="H">Simplify Graphics</span><br>Technical communicators and trainers often deal with content that regularly updates or needs to be translated for multiple languages.</p></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

FYI I'm really new to this so let me know if I am over-complicating things :)

Comment: this is works..

Comment: Have you cleared your browsers cache?

Comment: ` .H a:active` would never work because you have no `H` wrapper, `a:active` this would work if you have no other styles overriding the `span`. if there are overrides you could try `a:active .H {}` and it may work depending on how specific the overrides are. Easiest way to check for overrides is to inspect it and turn on the active pseudo class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your code using and modified just a touch. If you're just trying to target the  code within your `.H` class, then use the CSS showing in the snippet (`.H:active { color:#17CCB2; }`) As others have said, this does work as is, and I put it into a snippet so you can run it and see for yourself.

```css
.H:active { color:#17CCB2; }
```

```html
<div class="solution">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a id="FirstLink" href="javascript:" onclick="changeImg('images/auto-simp.gif');"><p class="solution-body"><span class="H">Auto Simplify</span><br>Automatically applies the Simplify Graphics for users that don't have the design tools, skills, or time to apply the SUI technique to their content.</p></a></li>
                            <li><a id="AC" href="javascript:" onclick="changeImg('images/auto-colors@2x.png')"><p class="solution-body"><span class="H">Auto Color Palette</span><br>Technical communicators and trainers often deal with content that regularly updates or needs to be translated for multiple languages.</p></a></li>
                            <li><a id="SG" href="javascript:" onclick="changeImg('images/simplifylaptop@2x.png')"><p class="solution-body"><span class="H">Simplify Graphics</span><br>Technical communicators and trainers often deal with content that regularly updates or needs to be translated for multiple languages.</p></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: This works but only when pressed, once I let go it turns back to the original color. Could it be because of the javascript I have for this piece of code?

window.setTimeout(clickit, 500);
function clickit(){
   document.getElementById("FirstLink").click();
}

Comment: no that's what `:active` does, it is only active when you press on it

Comment: Oh good to know thank you! Is there a way to get the link to stay that color until one of the other links is pressed?

Comment: What do you mean by selected? like you want it to show differently than the rest because you clicked on it? (can click elsewhere on the page and it stays different) or when the element is focused meaning you clicked on it and did not click anywhere else after, which is `:focus`

Comment: I would like the link to change colors when selected (let's say black to green) then when I click on a different link the first would go back to black. I just tried .H:focus and it doesn't seem to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Again, what exactly do you mean by 'selected'? After it's been clicked on and you want it to stay that color?

Comment: Yes! That is what I meant

Comment: You are looking for the `:visited` CSS selector then: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp. Your problem with this, though, is that you are not visiting a link when clicking on the `<a>` tag, rather you are calling a script. I'm not quite sure if it will work the same.

Comment: Hmm for some reason this isn't working either. Do I need to use javascript?

Comment: What you are looking for is an on state basically, you would need to add a class to the item that is clicked say `.active` class then with css change the colour, when you click on a different link, remove the active class then add the active class to the clicked element. Yes it will require js

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it, sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: No problem! Thanks for the assistance @Huangism

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.H:active` directly. This will select the exact element that you are targeting by targeting the H class

Comment: Little bit more explanation goes a long way but this would work

Comment: instead of using .H a:active { color:#17CCB2; }   use .H:active { color:#17CCB2; }

Comment: You can edit your answer, and by explanation I mean explain why your answer is better/works